# Python3 模擬試験でどうしても理解できない問題があり、教えていただきたい

Tags: python

Python3 基礎認定試験の勉強をしていますが、Prime Studyの模擬試験で、回答をみても何故そうなるのか分かりません。ご説明いただけるとありがたいです。

**問題**

```
[A][B][C]に入る適切な選択肢を選べ 

【実行結果】
Need Speed?
I'm Saya.
Need Speed?
I'm David.
```

```
class Kusanagi():
    def s(self):
        print("Need Speed?")
        [A]
    def m(self):
        print("I'm Saya.")
class wexal(kusanagi):
    def [B]:
        print("I'm David.")

k=kusanagi()
w=wexal
k.s()
w.[C]
```

**回答**

```
[A] self.m()
[B] m(self)
[C] s()
```

**疑問**

- [A] の `self.m()` の意味がわかりません
- [B] はインスタンス化しているということでしょうか？
- [C] は空の `()` を定義しているのでしょうか？

ご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 選択肢には何があってあなたは何を選んだのでしょうか？ また質問のコードを実行するといくつかエラーが出ます。質問のコードと回答は正しいものでしょうか？

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。確認しましたが、問題（コード）、回答とも合っています。。選択肢ですが、採点結果には正答しか記載されていないので全部はわかりませんが、以下、私が選んだ不正解の回答です。[A]self.s() [B]m(self) [C] s()

Comment: コードの問題点についてはkunifさんの回答にある通りです。

Answer (score 4):

ちなみに質問時の転記ミスでしょうか、classが`Kusanagi`で他は`kusanagi`と、`K`の大文字小文字が混在しています。
そして`w=wexal`では後ろの`()`が不足しています。

---

クラスの継承とメソッドのオーバーライドに関するものですね。
例えばこちらの記事が参考になるでしょう。
[【Python入門】クラスの継承、メソッドのオーバーライドとsuper](https://code-graffiti.com/class-inheritance-in-python/)

その上で、答えは以下になります。

**[A]の`self.m()`の意味がわかりません**

自分のインスタンスの`m`メソッドを呼び出しています。

**[B]はインスタンス化しているということでしょうか？**

親クラスのメソッドと同じ名前のメソッドをオーバーライドして定義しています。
`wexal`クラスインスタンスで`m`メソッドが実行された場合は、こちらの処理が行われます。

**[C]は空の`()`を定義しているのでしょうか？**

`wexal`クラスの`s`メソッドを呼び出しています。

`wexal`自身には`s`メソッドが無いので、親クラスから継承した`s`メソッドを実行します。
`s`メソッドを呼び出す際の`self`は`wexal`クラスのインスタンスなので、`s`メソッドの中で`self.m()`を実行した場合は`wexal`クラスの`m`メソッドが実行されて、表示するのは`I'm David.`になります。

---

この部分のコードを実行して：

```
k=kusanagi()
w=wexal()
k.s()
w.[C]
```

こちらの結果を得るためには：

```
Need Speed?
I'm Saya.
Need Speed?
I'm David.
```

大体以下のような考え方が必要で、その結果として答えが決定されます。

- 2つのクラスのインスタンスのそれぞれ1回の呼び出しで、上記4行の表示が必要
- つまり1回の呼び出しで2行表示される
- `kusanagi`クラスの`s`メソッドで2行目の`I'm Saya.`が表示されるためには、`s`メソッドの中で自身の`m`メソッドを呼ぶ必要がある → **[A]の回答**
- `kusanagi`クラスを継承した`wexal`クラスで1行目(表示としては3行目)の`Need Speed?`が表示されるためには、`s`メソッドを呼ぶ必要がある → **[C]の回答**
- `kusanagi`クラスを継承した`wexal`クラスの`s`メソッドで2行目(表示としては4行目)に`I'm David.`が表示されるためには、`m`メソッドをオーバーライド(同名のメソッドを定義)して、その中で`I'm David.`を表示する必要がある → **[B]の回答**